# Struggling with Proof of Prandtl's Boundary Layer Equations

Tags: partial-derivative, physics, fluid-dynamics, boundary-layer

Would someone with knowledge in fluid mechanics please help me in understanding this man's argument for why dp/dy, the pressure gradient in the boundary layer, must equal zero?
I would greatly appreciate this as I have watched his video numerous times trying to follow his argument.
His reasoning is at the 2:28 mark in the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3RuIhR6TTU&index=5&list=PLPhpE8md80HOfBesybSGUcba2YWce4_fz

Comment: he is just making some scale approximations. Eliminate terms that are not of sufficient magnitude.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_analysis_(mathematics)